# Angular Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I came across this angular timer that works perfectly for me. However, I can’t seem to successfully get it to stop when it reaches the countdown date. I basically want it to stop at 00:00:00. 
Any help?
[Angular Countdown Timer](https://codepen.io/prad3eep/pen/KoQJrp)

```
Check Codepen for code
```

Comment: We don't have long to live....

Comment: Don't cheat the system. If it asks for [mcve], please provide it. Codepen is a bonus

Comment: Did any of the given solutions work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly the problem, here the solution, it is not in CoffeScript (it's pretty simple to adapt however), it's in plain old javascript. I commented the edits

```
(function() {
  angular.module('app', []).directive('countdown', [
    'Util',
    '$interval',
    function(Util,
    $interval) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          date: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope,
    element) {
          var future;
          future = new Date(scope.date);
          //----you need to keep a reference to $interval----
          var int = $interval(function() {
            var diff;
            diff = Math.floor((future.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
            //----just check for the value of 'diff' when it becomes 0 you have to clear $interval
            if(diff===0) {
              $interval.cancel(int);
              return element.text("BOOM!")
            }
            return element.text(Util.dhms(diff));
          },
    1000);
        }
      };
    }
  ]).factory('Util', [
    function() {
      return {
        dhms: function(t) {
          var days,
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds;
          days = Math.floor(t / 86400);
          t -= days * 86400;
          hours = Math.floor(t / 3600) % 24;
          t -= hours * 3600;
          minutes = Math.floor(t / 60) % 60;
          t -= minutes * 60;
          seconds = t % 60;
          return [days + 'd',
    hours + 'h',
    minutes + 'm',
    seconds + 's'].join(' ');
        }
      };
    }
  ]);

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this will work for you, in Coffee Script, you should be able to copy this right into your example. The key is to print out when the diff reaches zero, and then cancel the timer.

```
angular.module 'app', []

.directive 'countdown', ['Util', '$interval', (Util, $interval) ->
  restrict: 'A'
  scope:
    date: '@'
  link: (scope, element) ->    
    future = new Date scope.date
    int = $interval ->
      diff = Math.floor (future.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000
      if (diff >= 0)
        element.text  Util.dhms diff
      else
        element.text  Util.dhms 0
        $interval.cancel int
    , 1000
    return
]

.factory 'Util', [ ->
  {
    dhms: (t) ->
      days = Math.floor t / 86400
      t -= days * 86400
      hours = Math.floor(t / 3600) % 24
      t -= hours * 3600
      minutes = Math.floor(t / 60) % 60
      t -= minutes * 60
      seconds = t % 60
      [ days + 'd', hours + 'h', minutes + 'm', seconds + 's' ].join ' '
  }
]
```